# error: object StreamingContext is not a member of package org.apache.spark.streaming import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

I'm trying to import sparkContext, but I recived that error:

> error: object StreamingContext is not a member of package org.apache.spark.streaming import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext

My code is:

```
package com.sundogsoftware.sparkstreaming

import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import collection.mutable._
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.apache.spark
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010._
...
```

I'm using maven on intelliJ, my pom is:

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1</version>
  <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
  <description>My wonderfull scala app</description>
  <inceptionYear>2015</inceptionYear>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>My License</name>
      <url>http://....</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <scala.version>2.11.8</scala.version>
    <scala.compat.version>2.11</scala.compat.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.specs2</groupId>
          <artifactId>specs2-junit_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.16</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.specs2</groupId>
      <artifactId>specs2-core_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.16</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
      <artifactId>scalatest_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>0.10.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
          <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.1</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
          <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
          <version>0.10.0.0</version>
      </dependency>


      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
          <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.0</version>
      </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <!-- see http://davidb.github.com/scala-maven-plugin -->
        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <args>
              <!-- <arg>-make:transitive</arg> -->
              <arg>-dependencyfile</arg>
              <arg>${project.build.directory}/.scala_dependencies</arg>
            </args>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.18.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <useFile>false</useFile>
        <disableXmlReport>true</disableXmlReport>
        <!-- If you have classpath issue like NoDefClassError,... -->
          <!-- useManifestOnlyJar>false</useManifestOnlyJar -->
          <includes>
            <include>**/*Test.*</include>
            <include>**/*Suite.*</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I use Gradle but try checking your project model and make sure the jar is listed under your Dependencies tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. It was due to my groupId, artifactId and version were the same as one of my dependencies.

```
<groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
<version>2.1.1</version>
```

and

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I've changed the first.